# Tire Sidewall Damage

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

Cut a corner too close when I was parking and scraped a curb. How big of a problem is this..? Safe to drive or not?

[image]

Comment: DEFINITELY replace this tire. Do not drive on it.

Answer (score 7):

That should be replaced and **really** soon - don't go on a freeway / motorway with it like that, as it looks deep. Even running around town it should be replaced asap...

Comment: Agree, it's toast, get it replaced right away.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of but didn't drive it this morning to be on the safe side. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 4):

Sidewall damage such as shown cannot be repaired.  Furthermore, any sidewall damage, because of mechanical forces and the materials nature, is subject to catastrophic failure.  This could be a blow out, while at highway speeds in heavy traffic, which creates an extreme risk.

To answer your questions: Big problem, not fixable, needs new tire. NOT safe.

Answer (score -2):

Try this. Take a pressure gauge and monitor how much air is being lost every 4 hours. If it went flat down to less than 10 psi, replacement is necessary. If there is no air loss or minimal of 1 psi per 4 hours, there are bandaid patches available with instructions and glue plus a heater, use that.

Just remember, 'bandaid' is a temp fix. I will not be responsible if it doesn't hold anymore or if you hit another curb what the end result might account to.

You be the judge whether you want an aid or a full replacement.

Everyone will try to convince you to their logic, I'm showing you dealer level patch jobs (not always the safest).

Comment: The law depends on what country you are in, but in the UK repairing sidewall damage like the OP's picture is just plain **illegal**. If you get pulled over by the police for any reason (or are involved in a not-your-fault accident), the court case that follows the police doing a 30-second "walk round" inspection of your car will cost you a lot more than a new tire would, quite apart from the safety issues.

Comment: DON'T try this, a pressure loss test will not check the strength of the sidewall under load either cornering or weight. You have family and friends who care about you.

Comment: Just another note to confirm, but a sidewall can be damaged and not result in any pressure loss until the tire fails (usually catastrophically, if in use).   I'm having trouble picturing how that tire is still holding any air, and how scraping a curb did that.